# Returning data resolved by XMLHttpRequest with module pattern function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, revealing-module-pattern

I have problem combining javascript callbacks and revealing module pattern.
What I'm trying to do is to return the HTTP response text with the `carsData.getCars()` function method.

Basically what I want to do is:

1. return the data from `xhr.onreadystatechange` function to the private `getData` function
2. return the data from `getData` function to the public `getCars` function ( or call the `getCars` function returning a value)

I got it to work with the synchronous AJAX mode, but I'm aware it's not the best practice in javascript development.

I tried to get it to work with callbacks but failed miserably.
Is it even posible to do in javascript?

P.S. I use `XMLHttpRequest` in Vanilla JS instead of other frameworks for learning purposes.

```
'use strict';
var carsData = (function() {
    var carsElement = document.getElementById('carsListing'),
        successHandler = function(data) {
            carsElement.innerHTML = data.data;
            //return data;
        },
        dataWrapper = "",
        getData = function(callback) {
            var url = 'data/cars.json',
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                var status;
                var data;

                if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
                    status = xhr.status;
                    if (status == 200) {
                        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        successHandler && successHandler(data);
                        callback(data);
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.open('get', url, false); // synchronous js
            xhr.send();
            return xhr.onreadystatechange();
            //return 'xx';
        }

    return {
        getCars: function() {
            return getData(function(data){
              console.log(data); // Object {data: Array[5]}
            })
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: You should take a look at [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promisifying-xmlhttprequest). They are not yet supported in all browsers, but are the way to go and used in several frameworks (with their respective implementation). You can return a promise in your modular pattern and resolve it later on.

Comment: Thank you @ssc-hrep3 , I will definitely look into it and try to wrap my head around it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You cannot do it this way.  I figured out that is why you typically see results sent to a DOM object.  Because they are there waiting for the answer.  Your return statement, as counter-intuitive as it seems (assuming you are coming from non-prototype languages), will have already run.  It seems like it wouldn't but it has because of the async nature you are aware of.  You have to use Promises or you have to have your callback doing something with the data that is "waiting" for the callback data like you did with `successdata`.